# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: maven, surefire

I am executing a selenium webdriver maven project on remote webdrivers and everytime I run it the actual test case passes but the build fails due to the following error

This is the output of my run in console. Please can someone help me to resolve this issue.

```
Running TestSuite
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Oct 02, 2014 1:03:47 PM com.test.perioddelay.Log info
INFO: ##################################
Oct 02, 2014 1:03:47 PM com.test.perioddelay.Log info
INFO: This is Silverscreentest-men
Maximize the browser-window
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Click on order now- period delay
Confirm checkbox is pre-selected
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Switch to frame
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Wait for 6 seconds
Take screenshot
Wait for 6 seconds
Oct 02, 2014 1:05:04 PM com.test.perioddelay.Log info
INFO: ##################################
Oct 02, 2014 1:05:04 PM com.test.perioddelay.Log info
INFO: This is Silverscreentest-men
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 120.671 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:47.092s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 02 13:05:04 BST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.1:test (default-test) on project com.test: Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExc`enter code here`eption

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is my POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>perioddelay</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12-beta-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                      <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>






</project>
```

Comment: What command do you actually run?

Comment: Why do you use maven-surefire-plugin for integration tests. For integration tests the maven-failsafe-plugin is the better choice.

Comment: Hi Kkuilla,the command I run is just the usual maven command which is clean compile test. I dont have the failsafe plugin in my pom. Should I add it and give it a try

Comment: Maybe not related, but why such an old version of `maven-surefire-plugin`?

Comment: Thats because I tried some resolution posted in stackoverflow. Hence the low version. I even tried with 2.17 but no luck

Comment: When I get this error `mvn clean` often remedies it.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the forkMode config property.  Move to latest version of surefire.

Comment: Can you let me know where can I find this in order for me to remove it?

Comment: Hi I think the issue is resolved based on your suggestion. I removed the fork mode property like below - :<configuration>
                                            <forkMode>never</forkMode>Thank you very much for your suggestion as I was struggling with this issue for more than a day.